# I'm having issues with nix-shell

Tags: plutus, plutus-playground, nix, nixos, nix-shell

I keep getting this error, any thoughts? I have re-downloaded nix 3 times now and it's the same error as before. Not sure if it's the profiles or channels but this is what it gives me:

```
'''trying https://bintray.com/joneshf/generic/download_file?file_path=purty-6.2.0-osx.tar.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found
error: cannot download download_file?file_path=purty-6.2.0-osx.tar.gz from any mirror
builder for '/nix/store/h5r5c5d2hq01xkdppsic3bl6qacc3wqj-download_file?file_path=purty-6.2.0-osx.tar.gz.drv' failed with exit code 1
building '/nix/store/ymrrdyw3n26pj4slkcmcqbmmyzd5k10k-edit-distance-lib-edit-distance-0.2.2.1-config.drv'...
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/w2j8cjba5cq80q8874c5zy2n4p6cjn11-purty-6.2.0.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
error: build of '/nix/store/00czvl77x4dsjgyacq2i0ndknq1nhpig-sort-lib-sort-1.0.0.0.drv', '/nix/store/1skqzb2qn4cgh2wca78p3d7x8dzkwl6x-update-metadata-samples.drv', '/nix/store/24q0nd586wkyap6v79kcrk5141n2gj10-cabal-install-exe-cabal-3.4.0.0.drv', '/nix/store/2phjywsqy1607ing23kbwibh2aljsi2r-fix-stylish-haskell.drv', '/nix/store/31z19v2i3iibmfq76gyv5pqcr55976zv-updateMaterialized.drv', '/nix/store/3m344smmhpl6w0agwrf3h51h06smh28s-haskell-language-server-exe-haskell-language-server-1.1.0.0.drv', '/nix/store/51nz2l60xlkcg3kfml4115n9ndl37hjz-morph-1.5.0.drv', '/nix/store/6kqxqav9rh7fqi0csxzj9s4806i7vh75-signal-lib-signal-0.1.0.4.drv', '/nix/store/6lqh7knn0dfxdbmrm1xfn38dq1l8d29j-streaming-binary-lib-streaming-binary-0.2.2.0.drv', '/nix/store/6mmj5jxczlzdizisc0xlw18k84iwx9hz-agdaWithPackages-2.6.1.1.drv', '/nix/store/7kbhkhpilggidv66brc587jrkvkhq69n-partial-order-lib-partial-order-0.2.0.0.drv', '/nix/store/8012yr8janh31vlsjays761clvz20ami-ieee754-lib-ieee754-0.8.0.drv', '/nix/store/85npd6ymfj0q8wg92mzjsmdq0k41js85-r-dplyr-1.0.2.drv', '/nix/store/8j74dj2y8avqb5k6slnrn049lgzprvhg-hlint-exe-hlint-3.2.1.drv', '/nix/store/9820n0i8vhzgiiacpx2i6i6nyrsaway5-validation-lib-validation-1.1.1.drv', '/nix/store/9aqg02hwpvkvbh12cnmkdr0jf5qbc6dz-tree-diff-lib-tree-diff-0.2.drv', '/nix/store/9isss0nqik8hsmhymkx2gyq115xjs36y-sbv-lib-sbv-8.14.drv', '/nix/store/9lasjc950dfsn71hv9r8rzhspcscirg9-pretty-simple-lib-pretty-simple-4.0.0.0.drv', '/nix/store/bbidfihkb8x2gaf1fb2d8yjkfpqhm7xa-r-tidyverse-1.3.0.drv', '/nix/store/bdxspighrzkiip40jfnhbwnnia58bh0f-microlens-mtl-lib-microlens-mtl-0.2.0.1.drv', '/nix/store/c0kv959f5aq51cyzl4qnbpsvk88ps3m1-tdigest-lib-tdigest-0.2.1.1.drv', '/nix/store/c144bf3zwkpam1kbn04y97xhxfd9w601-generic-monoid-lib-generic-monoid-0.1.0.1.drv', '/nix/store/d6n0fpqh61s8x1ml1ighn8g8knv2qbxf-r-shiny-1.5.0.drv', '/nix/store/fsfi7xcvqrl6fcma5r1cs13yd277s618-streaming-bytestring-lib-streaming-bytestring-0.2.0.drv', '/nix/store/gbk4dp9gz0ggx66057nyi4gkv61j3a15-tasty-smallcheck-lib-tasty-smallcheck-0.8.2.drv', '/nix/store/gl9jrf8hc3ylpsplr8n2hs51xsn4nmbi-python3-3.8.6-env.drv', '/nix/store/gp6jgd67y75js5s3ackfkb5iszmzybsl-inline-r-lib-inline-r-0.10.4.drv', '/nix/store/hfv786xib23lfjk74lzxlrmm103q6v4s-r-plotly-4.9.2.2.drv', '/nix/store/i1igk4bviddh52vssqlm07hzf9j449p6-quickcheck-text-lib-quickcheck-text-0.1.2.1.drv', '/nix/store/ijzzvvq1kd953qhpiar696iqh8bxpgf9-r-shinyjs-2.0.0.drv', '/nix/store/ik042p673z6539x4zdp65k6xqmdkq0m6-ghc-shell-for-packages-ghc-8.10.4.20210212-env.drv', '/nix/store/ivgidgaa262s5javry9frg0hzckicbmw-r-purrr-0.3.4.drv', '/nix/store/j11byvlsxjykg0ynmddnqrf9d75wg5w5-typerep-map-lib-typerep-map-0.3.3.0.drv', '/nix/store/j678ky26621ys0jk651b7263cg7yn66z-extensible-effects-lib-extensible-effects-5.0.0.1.drv', '/nix/store/jzvxxyyqpbhbkfxxw2ac7hj8r57bb8by-process-extras-lib-process-extras-0.7.4.drv', '/nix/store/k9m80yh5wmrmic44nvlq57ll3nv5k334-tasty-expected-failure-lib-tasty-expected-failure-0.12.3.drv', '/nix/store/kkwfwqhfp5dr7s8xfwnvhz7h5hrpbq29-rate-limit-lib-rate-limit-1.4.2.drv', '/nix/store/lyvsqqnghjbspwp3zf0417zlhn49s51i-hspec-expectations-pretty-diff-lib-hspec-expectations-pretty-diff-0.7.2.5.drv', '/nix/store/m0wwdkv6dca42i8ii6h08k3j94j0fpmk-loch-th-lib-loch-th-0.2.2.drv', '/nix/store/mc8v4zm1vxj32mqhkbvc2h1r3s43x4bg-hspec-lib-hspec-2.7.9.drv', '/nix/store/mhd5irwlzbyzxxsbqrywlxxnkffm1gfm-hie-bios-exe-hie-bios-0.7.5.drv', '/nix/store/nkrkj480lwidfalwmijip0z3lpajllys-groups-lib-groups-0.5.2.drv', '/nix/store/nw0pm1c6pjxmxh3nm32y8c43igzm6v9s-pure-zlib-lib-pure-zlib-0.6.7.drv', '/nix/store/pmmbzhgf4qsd0sjfj61mak31a3b22z7x-r-stringr-1.4.0.drv', '/nix/store/qv7yjyqpby61b10876kg3w92qyqv7vks-tasty-quickcheck-lib-tasty-quickcheck-0.10.1.2.drv', '/nix/store/r290xlyhhrx7720f82b7piqs8q3bsidn-r-MASS-7.3-53.drv', '/nix/store/ssp8icp0lrb42dnkgzz3hbq9jcvnckzb-wl-pprint-lib-wl-pprint-1.2.1.drv', '/nix/store/vpbn2q57ljbdnryffkkg9yh574q92rif-moo-lib-moo-1.2.drv', '/nix/store/w0jpaqn7bm0j961kvqfbq9p6vn45l4dp-pre-commit-config.json.drv', '/nix/store/w2j8cjba5cq80q8874c5zy2n4p6cjn11-purty-6.2.0.drv', '/nix/store/w6hkfwbk4y92rj3y689sq5jhhcmgz9gh-update-client-deps.drv', '/nix/store/wmkc31ic82raw02wj75dihcp2cr442zl-gauge-lib-gauge-0.2.5.drv', '/nix/store/wra9k298zi1h037jyqk6d81d0pzl5g4w-criterion-lib-criterion-1.5.9.0.drv', '/nix/store/xjil71bs00sidlp6bmlnw1crzrpzbnig-z3.drv', '/nix/store/xs5fcb6zahna29znlpfxvfb6rhcd3qd6-cassava-lib-cassava-0.5.2.0.drv', '/nix/store/yw23258yf4idsinig1ac06h8gb4y347l-fix-purty.drv', '/nix/store/z8h2jvfqxzzcnbx9lv0vrnq52b4kj114-hint-lib-hint-0.9.0.4.drv', '/nix/store/zcyridhi051675splnihx5myd7599wd4-stylish-haskell-exe-stylish-haskell-0.12.2.0.drv', '/nix/store/ziifb1divbpabkg3dqkv1c0qi0bdhsnj-smallcheck-lib-smallcheck-1.2.1.drv', '/nix/store/zivnf3s09nf4l0zk8wi6gxr5s6av7x43-pipes-lib-pipes-4.3.15.drv', '/nix/store/zp3asyqhf3538a7x9cc5a3sb8xb2hjkc-tasty-hedgehog-lib-tasty-hedgehog-1.1.0.0.drv' failed'''
```

Comment: Can you please share which exact commit and branch you are trying?

Answer (score 8):

It may help to use IOHK's binary caches.

You can set these up globally for your system by adding/creating these lines in `/etc/nix/nix.conf`:

```
substituters        = https://hydra.iohk.io https://iohk.cachix.org https://cache.nixos.org/
trusted-public-keys = hydra.iohk.io:f/Ea+s+dFdN+3Y/G+FDgSq+a5NEWhJGzdjvKNGv0/EQ= iohk.cachix.org-1:DpRUyj7h7V830dp/i6Nti+NEO2/nhblbov/8MW7Rqoo= cache.nixos.org-1:6NCHdD59X431o0gWypbMrAURkbJ16ZPMQFGspcDShjY=
```

Comment: I have tried that but the file is locked, so I duplicated and ran that and still is giving me the same error unfortunately. Im using MacOS M1,

Comment: I don't know if the ARM-based processor complicates things, but you can edit your file using sudo from the terminal. Prepend sudo to your favorite editor; for example run `sudo vim /etc/nix/nix.conf` to modify the file.

Comment: this worked for me, thanks

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I've added those lines and still get the same error

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple different types of nix.conf files in the $PATH, even when I made one globally. So What I initial did was replace all of them with the IOHK's binary caches, and from there it worked.