# 403 Forbidden when trying to run nix-shell during setup for Plutus Pioneer Program

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program, nix-shell

I've seen other questions similar to this about a 404 error, but this is different.
I have the IOHK Plutus cache set up as per the instructions.

Getting the following error:

```
trying https://bintray.com/joneshf/generic/download_file?file_path=purty-6.2.0-linux.tar.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 403 Forbidden
error: cannot download download_file?file_path=purty-6.2.0-linux.tar.gz from any mirror
builder for '/nix/store/g0drypafpyzckkpwzplp9k9amx4bf7a4-download_file?file_path=purty-6.2.0-linux.tar.gz.drv' failed with exit code 1
building '/nix/store/m63hg37ygw5xkjkd429xds19qkffr6m3-easy-file-lib-easy-file-0.2.2-config.drv'...
cannot build derivation '/nix/store/wdgbj9xf3rz44xz5afw20m1ns0n8llpg-purty-6.2.0.drv': 1 dependencies couldn't be built
error: build of '/nix/store/05snx37ayscns4jfqq62v8ignps9izml-plutus-pab-generate-purs.drv', '/nix/store/08hhl408j6anygi2xf33xjdq4ciy2mxp-loch-th-lib-loch-th-0.2.2.drv', .....
```

I'm running on windows via WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) running Ubuntu

Comment: Please try the methods given https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/413/im-having-issues-with-nix-shell.

Comment: Yes, I've already tried those suggestions. Same result

Comment: The nix is trying to download from bintry which is outdated. Please update the question with details of your nix installation including version.

Comment: Ok thanks! I'll refresh my vm and try again

Comment: I'll update the question too

Comment: @raghu looks like I built on an incorrect branch initially, that caused problems later. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it looks like I initially built on the master branch by mistake. Switching to the correct branch and recompiling didn't help the situation.
I reset my WSL instance of Ubuntu and started again, more carefully this time. Everything worked as it should.